# Sort a scrambled itinerary (Google apac test problem)

Tags: algorithm, ruby, programming-challenge, graph

This is my first time writing ruby - and I was mainly hoping to get some feedback and stylistic pointers.

The algorithm is pretty straight-forward, since Google guarantees airports aren't repeated I store all the tickets in a hash table and then sort from random insertion points, which should be worst case \$O(n \log n)\$.

[Original problem description](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6214486/dashboard#s=p2)

> Once upon a day, Mary bought a one-way ticket from somewhere to somewhere with some flight transfers. For example: SFO->DFW DFW->JFK JFK->MIA MIA->ORD.
>
> Unfortunately, after she received the tickets, she messed up the tickets and she forgot the order of the tickets.
>
> Help Mary rearrange the tickets to make the tickets in correct order.

```
def merge_ordered_flights(ordered_flights) 
    while ordered_flights.size > 1 
        flights = ordered_flights.pop
        ordered_flights.each do |a| 
            if a[0] == flights[-1] 
                a.insert(0, *flights)
                break
            elsif a[-1] == flights[0] 
                a.insert(-1, *flights)
                break
            end
        end
    end
    return ordered_flights[0] #flatten
end

def order_flights(tickets)
    ordered_flights = []
    iter = 0
    while true
        #Get an arbitrary arrival, destination flight pair
        arv, dest = tickets.shift
        if arv == nil 
            break #Done if we are out of tickets
        end
        ordered_flights[iter] = []
        ordered_flights[iter].push(arv, dest)
        #And append follow-up destinations until we can't find one
        #(It's the final destination, or the other tickets have already been sorted)
        while true 
            arv = dest 
            dest = tickets.delete(dest)
            if dest == nil 
                break #End of current chain
            end
            ordered_flights[iter].push(arv, dest)
        end
        iter += 1
    end
    #Now combine the ordered flight arrays into a single array 
    return merge_ordered_flights(ordered_flights)
end

def print_flights(case_num, ordered_flights) 
    flights = (0...ordered_flights.size).step(2).map {|i| ordered_flights[i] + '-' + ordered_flights[i+1] }.join ' '
    puts "CASE ##{case_num}: #{flights}"
end

while not $stdin.eof?
    num_cases = $stdin.readline.strip.to_i
    (1..num_cases).each {
        |num|
        tickets = {} 
        num_flights = $stdin.readline.strip.to_i
        (0...num_flights).each {
            tickets[$stdin.readline.strip] = $stdin.readline.strip 
        }
        ordered_flights = order_flights(tickets)
        print_flights(num, ordered_flights)
    }
end
```

Example input:

> The first line contains the number of test cases T, after which T cases follow.
>   For each case, it starts with an integer N. There are N flight tickets follow.
>   Each of the next 2 lines contains the source and destination of a flight ticket.

```
2
1
SFO
DFW
4
MIA
ORD
DFW
JFK
SFO
DFW
JFK
MIA
```

Expected output:

```
Case #1: SFO-DFW
Case #2: SFO-DFW DFW-JFK JFK-MIA MIA-ORD
```

Comment: Since links can rot, [please include a description of the challenge here in your question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1993)

Comment: @200_success is it alright to quote verbatim from the page? Should I try and give a terser description?

Comment: @user3467349 I went ahead and added some of the text from the original problem description (shortened it a little). Most important bit is the example input and output, since that'll let reviewers verify your code and any changes they might make.

Comment: The page says that its license is CC-BY, so it is allowable to quote verbatim. The way Flambino summarized it is good too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Style notes:

- The Ruby convention is [2 spaces of indentation](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)
- Use braces for single-line blocks, but `do...end` for multi-line blocks.
- Keep the block parameters on the starting line; i.e. don't do this

  ```
  (1..num_cases).each {
      |num|
  ```
- Use `#nil?` rather than `== nil`, `empty?` when checking array lengths, `#first`/`#last` when accessing the start/end of an array, etc..
- Postfix conditions for single-line, single-branch conditionals. E.g. this:

  ```
  if arv == nil 
      break #Done if we are out of tickets
  end
  ```

  becomes:

  ```
  break if arv.nil? # Done if we are out of tickets
  ```
- Instead of iterating through ranges like `(0...n)` you can use `n.times` instead. E.g. `n.times { |i| puts i }` will produce the same as `(0...n).each { |i| puts i }`
- You missed a single pair of parentheses in a method call: `.join ' '` :)
  Granted, you can write Ruby without parentheses (Seattle style Ruby). Personally though, I like 'em (except for `puts` and `print`), but [there are arguments for and against](http://heartmindcode.com/2013/09/05/parentheses-in-ruby/).

#### Code notes:

Instead of `$stdin.readline.strip`, you can use the more common `gets.chomp`. `#gets` is just a shortcut for `$stdin.readline`, and `#chomp` chops off the linebreak, but leaves other whitespace intact.

When possible use methods like `#map` and `#reduce` and their ilk instead of modifying a closed-over object from inside a block. E.g. this:

```
tickets = {} 
# ...
(0...num_flights).each {
    tickets[$stdin.readline.strip] = $stdin.readline.strip 
}
```

can be written in a few different ways - `#each_with_object` is probably the cleanest:

```
tickets = num_flights.times.each_with_object({}) do |_, tickets|
  tickets[gets.chomp] = gets.chomp
end
```

Alternatively, you could read the lines, and chunk them up afterward:

```
lines = (num_flights * 2).times { gets.chomp }
tickets = Hash[ lines.each_slice(2).to_a ]
```

You can do something similar in `#print_flights` instead of using `step(2)`:

```
def print_flights(case_num, ordered_flights)
  tickets = ordered_flights.each_slice(2).map { |pair| pair.join("-") }
  puts "CASE ##{case_num}: #{tickets.join(" ")}"
end
```

Typically, Ruby coders avoid "raw" array indices and index arithmetic like `array[i+1]` in favor of more expressive code.

Lastly, `#order_flights` has side-effects: It deletes entries from the `tickets` hash you pass to it. Sure, it doesn't matter for this particular exercise, but side-effects are side-effects and should be avoided.

---

The algorithm itself looks fine to me. I might write it like so:

```
def read_tickets
  count = gets.chomp.to_i
  count.times.map do
    [gets.chomp, gets.chomp]
  end
end

def sort_tickets(tickets)
  flights = tickets.dup # make a copy to modify
  stops = flights.shift
  until flights.empty?
    from, to = flights.shift
    if from == stops.last
      stops.push(to) # could also use <<, but #push keeps "symmetry" with #unshift
    elsif to == stops.first
      stops.unshift(from)
    else
      flights.push [from, to]
    end
  end
  stops.each_cons(2).to_a
end

case_count = gets.chomp.to_i
case_count.times do |t|
  tickets = read_tickets
  ordered = sort_tickets(tickets).map { |ticket| ticket.join("-") }
  puts "Case ##{t+1}: #{ordered.join(" ")}"
end
```

Pretty much the same algorithm, just written differently. Notice however that I never actually use hashes, just nested arrays. Unfortunately, it's *sloooow* (the `else` branch and `#each_cons` are probably to blame, but I haven't checked). Still, style-wise it might give you some ideas.

An alternative, which *does* use hashes, would be to scan the tickets to find the first leg of the journey. After that, a single loop through should put them in order.

```
def read_tickets
  count = gets.chomp.to_i
  count.times.each_with_object({}) do |_, tickets|
    tickets[gets.chomp] = gets.chomp
  end
end

def print_sorted_tickets(tickets)
  inverted = tickets.invert
  from, to = tickets.detect { |from, to| inverted[from].nil? } # find first
  print " #{from}-#{to}"
  while tickets[to]
    from, to = [to, tickets[to]]
    print " #{from}-#{to}"
  end
  print "\n"
end

case_count = gets.chomp.to_i
case_count.times do |t|
  print "Case ##{t+1}:"
  tickets = read_tickets
  print_sorted_tickets(tickets)
end
```

I've combined sorting and printing only because I can. I'd prefer sorting and *then* printing, like above, or at least returning a string. The code can easily be changed to support that, but I figured I'd try combining the two. And this runs about as fast as your solution (somewhat surprisingly - I figured `#invert` would be more expensive).

By the way, one could "manually" create the inverse hash immediately when reading the input, instead of using `#invert`. But I don't think it'll make *that* much difference. Either case would be trading memory for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer. re: *finding the first leg of the journey* I thought of this as well, but I thought that would be slower than the merging ~logN sub-arrays. Timing your second solution though the difference appears to be pretty marginal (it's a little slower in my tests about ~2x), so I don't know if that's worth the effort. Probably all solutions using a hash-table instead of lists will run reasonably fast.

Comment: @user3467349 Glad it was useful. Good job for your first Ruby code, by the way! Funny about the 2nd solution; it was a a closer race on my computer (~1.5x for the large input file). Regardless, yeah, it's slower (I actually thought I wrote "about as fast as yours", not "as fast"; I'll edit that), but it saves some code. I think you'll find most Rubyists are willing to take a (small) performance hit if it makes for less code/more expressive code. Not that the above is a brilliant solution for either metric, but still. Ruby's focus is on making coders happy, rather than the computer :)

Comment: I guess I was trying too hard to be clever, when something much simpler would have been just as good =/

Comment: @user3467349 Don't say that. Cleverness is good; real cleverness is knowing when to not to be too clever :) Regardless, your code is still indisputably faster than either of my attempts. A smattering of Ruby's syntactic sugar (`first`, `last`, etc.), and it's a very neat solution. As an addendum to my previous comment, I should say that of course Rubyists care about their code's performance too, but when deciding on a speed vs expressiveness/readability trade-off, there's just that little bit of bias toward the latter. Not enough to absolve my 1st attempt, though - that's just plain slow :)