# Super2048 (Google apac Test Problem)

Tags: algorithm, ruby, programming-challenge

This is my second try at writing Ruby. Stylistic feedback is very much appreciated.

[The problem](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/3214486/dashboard#s=p1):

> 2048 is played on a simple 4 x 4 grid with tiles that slide smoothly
>   when a player moves them. For each movement, the player can choose to
>   move all tiles in 4 directions, left, right, up, and down, as far as
>   possible at the same time. If two tiles of the same number collide
>   while moving, they will merge into a tile with the total value of the
>   two tiles that collided. In one movement, one newly created tile can
>   not be merged again and always is merged with the tile next to it
>   along the moving direction first. E.g. if the three "2" are in a row
>   "2 2 2" and the player choose to move left, it will become "4 2 0",
>   the most left 2 "2" are merged.

The solution for Super2048 should produce the correct 2048 movement for any N-sized board (all boards are square).

Example Input:

```
1
4 right
2 0 2 4
2 0 4 2
2 2 4 8
2 2 4 4
```

Example Output:

```
Case #1:
0 0 4 4
0 2 4 2
0 4 4 8
0 0 4 8
```

The Algorithm - first we need identify the rules by which the board movement is made -- it seems that:

- Tiles move as far as possible along empty spaces
- If they collide (equal value) they merge
- Tiles fill in spaces created by merged tiles

Therefore my `board_move!` code looks like this:

```
def board_move!(board, move) 
    #move empties 
    move_rows!(board, move)
    #merge all eligible
    merge_rows!(board, move)
    #move into squares emptied by merge
    move_rows!(board, move)
end
```

It's notable that movement behaves the same in any direction, so if the algorithm could just rotate the board that would be enough. Unlike Python's Numpy - Ruby doesn't give N-dimensional arrays or a convenient rotate method. Here is an outline for the behaviour that the `merge_rows!` and `move_rows!` should produce:

```
"""
merge->left
a[0][0] <- a[0][1] 
a[1][0] <- a[1][1]
a[2][0] <- a[2][1]

merge->right 
a[0][2] <- a[0][1] 
a[1][2] <- a[1][1]
a[2][2] <- a[2][1] 

merge-> up
a[0][0] <- a[1][0]
a[0][1] <- a[1][1]
a[0][2] <- a[1][2]

merge-> down
a[2][0] <- a[1][0] 
a[2][1] <- a[1][1] 
a[2][2] <- a[1][2] 
"""
#Note that the +1 (merging and moving rows) need to have an index 1 less than size to not run out of bounds
#While the slots being merged in each row get the entire index
```

Therefore it should be enough to have an *inner* and an *outer* iterator and a constant for the `+1`. Here is the `merge_rows!` method. I didn't really like using the switch, but I think it's not possible to have a pointer to the iterators (`i`, `j`) so we re-assign on each loop. In terms of code optimization it should actually only assign `a` and `b` once at the top, reassign the outer index only every outer-loop and the inner-index every inner loop. I used a single switch to keep it readable - but some advice on how to have a both compact code and not reassign variables that stay constant would be very welcome (I'm not very happy with it atm).

```
def merge_rows!(board, move) 
    siz = board.size
    (siz-1).times do |i|
        (siz).times do |j|
            #puts "#{i} #{j}"
            case move 
                when "up"
                    a=1; b=0; x=i; y=j;
                when "down"
                    a=-1; b=0; x=siz-(i+1); y=j;
                when "left"
                    a=0; b=1; x=j; y=i;
                when "right"
                    a=0; b=-1; x=j; y=siz-(i+1);
            end
            #merge tiles of equal numbers
            if board[x][y] == board[x+a][y+b]
                board[x][y] *= 2
                board[x+a][y+b] = 0 
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Here is the `move_rows!` method. A notable difference from `merge_rows!` is that while rows can only merge once, a row can move up to `board.size-1` times.

```
def move_rows!(board, move)   
    #This relocates each slot by up to one row
    def _move_rows!(board, move, start)
        siz = board.size
        (siz-1-start).times do |i| 
            (siz).times do |j|
                #puts "#{i} #{j}"
                case move 
                    when "up"
                        a=1; b=0; x=i; y=j;
                    when "down"
                        a=-1; b=0; x=siz-(i+1); y=j;
                    when "left"
                        a=0; b=1; x=j; y=i;
                    when "right"
                        a=0; b=-1; x=j; y=siz-(i+1);
                end
                #move tiles into empty spaces
                if board[x][y] == 0 
                    board[x][y] = board[x+a][y+b]
                    board[x+a][y+b] = 0
                end
            end
        end
    end
    #We need to move to the first row up to siz-1 times, to the 2nd up to siz-2 times etc...
    #So we can pass a start distance to skip attempting to move rows more than necessary
    (board.size-1).times do |iter|
            _move_rows!(board, move, iter)  
    end
end
```

An alternative simplification for the above would be making the if statements for `merge` and `move` callable functions and passing them to a single `board_row_action` method.

That just leaves printing the board and parsing `stdin`:

```
#Correct problem format
def output_board(board, case_num) 
    puts "Case ##{case_num}:"
    board.each { |row| puts "#{row.join(' ')}" }
end

num_cases = gets.chomp.to_i
num_cases.times do |num|
    info = gets.chomp.split
    siz, move = info[0].to_i,  info[1]
    board = []
    siz.times do
        line = gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i)
        board.push(line) 
    end
    board_move!(board, move) 
    output_board(board, num+1)
end
```

Comment: Ruby has [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method, that with `.map(&:reverse)` is enough for any rotation. https://gist.github.com/Nakilon/10571155

Comment: @Nakilon :( someone should have told me earlier.

Comment: @user3467349 [Here's a more readable implementation](http://ideone.com/H8o2wC) - actually two different implementations - of matrix rotation that monkeypatches `Array`.

Comment: @Flambino Yes I didn't know there was a built in transpose =/

Answer (score 2):

#### Style notes:

- I've said it [before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90855/14370), but the Ruby convention is 2 spaces of indentation :)
- Also a repeat: Prefer methods like `#first` and `#last` for array access when possible. Or use array destructuring. E.g. this:

  ```
  info = gets.chomp.split
  siz, move = info[0].to_i,  info[1]
  ```

  can be written as:

  ```
  siz, move = gets.chomp.split
  ```

  though you'll have to call `#to_i` on `siz` when you need it. By the way, it'd be nicer to just call it `size` - there's no reason to drop a single letter.
- And prefer functional approaches, when possible. For instance, this:

  ```
  board = []
  siz.times do
      line = gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i)
      board.push(line) 
  end
  ```

  becomes:

  ```
  board = siz.times.map { gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i) }
  ```

#### Code notes:

The thing about rotating 2D arrays has been covered in the comments. That's probably the big-ticket item here, since using that will let you avoid a bunch of index arithmetic.

I'm not a fan of the nested method. It works, but it's not a terribly common construction. You could move the inner method out, or you could convert it to a proc. The latter has the benefit of closures, meaning you'd only have to pass it its `start` parameter - `board` and `move` are already in-scope. Such a proc would do all its work with side-effects, though.

Your move-merge-move strategy might instead be expressed as reject-merge-pad. I.e. we can reject all the zeros, and just merge what remains, then pad the result with new zeros. Given the row `[0, 2, 0, 2]` we can start by reducing it to `[2, 2]`, instead of trying to maintain its size.

Finally, there's the merging itself. I played around with a bunch of things (using `#each_cons` with variations on map/reduce, using a `Tile` class to allow tiles to be passed by reference, tried some stuff with `Enumerator` instances...), but in the end, I went with this:

```
def merge(row)
  return [] if row.empty?
  head, *tail = row
  if head == tail.first
    [head * 2] + merge(tail.drop(1))
  else
    [head] + merge(tail)
  end
end
```

Its input is a row/column of tiles with the zeros stripped away, and from that it - with some recursion - returns the merged result, again without zeros.

Combined with the array rotation, it seems to do the trick, and it seems fast. Haven't tried timing it, though.

In all, I ended up with this. I aimed for a functional approach, always returning new arrays instead of modifying existing ones in-place.

```
# Monkeypatch for Array
class Array
  def spin(times = 1)
    case times % 4
    when 1, -3
      transpose.map(&:reverse)
    when 2, -2
      reverse.map(&:reverse)
    when 3, -1
      map(&:reverse).transpose
    else
      self.dup # rotate 360; no change
    end
  end
end

# Lookup table of how to rotate the board before merging
ROTATIONS = { "right" => 0, "up" => 1, "left" => 2, "down" => 3 }.freeze

def move(board, direction)
  size = board.count
  rotation = ROTATIONS[direction]
  board.spin(rotation).map do |row|              # rotate then map
    merged = merge(row.reject(&:zero?))          # merge non-zero tiles
    merged.unshift(0) while merged.count < size  # pad row back to size
    merged
  end.spin(-rotation)                            # rotate back again
end

def merge(row)
  return [] if row.empty?
  head, *tail = row
  if head == tail.first
    [head * 2] + merge(tail.drop(1))
  else
    [head] + merge(tail)
  end
end

def print_board(board)
  puts board.map { |row| row.join(" ") }.join("\n")
end

cases = gets.chomp.to_i
cases.times do |n|
  size, direction = gets.chomp.split(" ")
  board = size.to_i.times.map { gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i) }
  result = move(board, direction)
  puts "Case #{n + 1}:"
  print_board(result)
end
```

Comment: Reject, unshift is a very nice touch. I'm not sure I agree with *though you'll have to call #to_i on siz afterward.* imho you should format your input correctly in one place. I guess `siz, move = gets.chomp.split; siz =  siz.to_i` would wok.

Comment: @user3467349 True it depends on the context. In my code, I only used the size input value in one place, so I read it as a string, but called `size.to_i.times...` to use it. I didn't alter the `size` variable itself after reading it: It remained a string. My 2nd choice would be your original code just using `#first` and `#last` rather than `[0]` and `[1]`. But I'd avoid doing something like `size = <some string>; size = size.to_i`. I generally don't like altering a variable's type after the fact (unless it's something like `x ||= <default value>`)

Comment: Also I know you aren't a big fan of indexing directly but why not something like: 
```def merge!(row)
    (row.size-1).times do |i| 
        if row[i] == row[i+1] 
            row[i] *=2;
            row[i+1] = 0;
        end
    end
    row.reject(&:zero?)
end``` for the `merge` method, a recursive call seems kind of unnecessary there. And in this case the indexing is easier to read I think.

Comment: @user3467349 That'd certainly work, and since it's a neat solution, I'd be fine with it (though I'd still try to come up with an alternative, just because). I thought something along the same lines, but was (too) fixated on trying to avoid using raw indices. Which, I admit, is probably a bit too zealous of me. But most often I've found code to be more elegant when not playing around with indices, so I try to look for such solutions. But, but, sometimes it's just more straightforward to get off the high horse :)